# Why my queries work weirdly?

Tags: php, mysql

I get this two queries with the same variables :

```
$query = 'UPDATE payee SET payee="oui", datePaiement=\'' . $datePaiement . '\',paiement="'.$paiement.'", typePaiement="' . utf8_decode($moyenPaiement) . '" WHERE id_commande=' . $commande->getNum() . '';
        $connexion->exec($query);

$query2 = 'UPDATE commande SET mpaiement="' . utf8_decode($moyenPaiement) . '",pxttc="'.$paiement.'" WHERE noCommande=" . $commande->getNum() . "';
        $connexion->exec($query2);
```

For the first one, my `$paiement` isn't save in my DB. I get a `$paiement = 0` while in my second one `$paiement` is save as I want.

I have the same pattern in my second query `$moyenPaiement`, `moyenPaiement` is save as I want but he is not save in my first query.

Sorry for my explanation, it's maybe confused.

Comment: Someone can explain me ? I really don't understand what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not combine both single and double quotes, it will be confusing. Try this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE payee SET payee="oui", datePaiement="' . $datePaiement . '", paiement="'.$paiement.'", typePaiement="' . utf8_decode($moyenPaiement) . '" WHERE id_commande="' . $commande->getNum() . '"';
        $connexion->exec($query);

$query2 = 'UPDATE commande SET mpaiement="' . utf8_decode($moyenPaiement) . '", pxttc="'.$paiement.'" WHERE noCommande="' . $commande->getNum() . '"';
        $connexion->exec($query2);
```

Later edit:
Don't forget to print your queries if something weird happens. These queries can be tested in phpMyAdmin too.

```
print_r($query);
```

Comment: That works for `$moyenPaiement` but my `$paiement` still doesn't work. I am in research.

Comment: What does output `print_r($query);` for both queries?